# How do I call a function in a parent object? (C++)

Tags: c++

Using the example below, I would like to call the function printTop() from my 'Bottom' object. It seems perhaps I could use a pointer to the parent object?

```
class Bottom {
public:
    void printBottom(){std::cout << "print bottom";};
};

class Top {
public:
    void printTop(){std::cout << "print top";};
private:
    Bottom bottom;
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can't call `printTop` from `Bottom` because `printTop` is a function of `Top`, and those two are not related. What do you mean?

Comment: Simply `void printTop(){std::cout << "print top"; bottom.printBottom(); };` what's your problem?

Comment: There is no "parent object" here. Time to rephrase in terms of what you're trying to acheve, not how you're currently trying to do it.

Comment: From Bottom, I'd like to call a function in the specific instance of Top in which it has been instantiated. I thought Top was the parent object of Bottom, as it where Bottom is instantiated (not parent class because there's no inheritance).

Comment: @user0042 that's what I'd like to do, but in the reverse direction! 

ie. void printBottom(){std::cout << "print bottom"; top.printTop()};

Comment: @JakeBug You can't. What do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: @JakeBug Membership is only known by the owner. A member is completely unaware of its surroundings.

Comment: Something like: printBottom(){std::cout << "print bottom"; top.printTop()};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is truly where your heart is at, it can be done (doesn't mean i'd advocate it):

```
class Top;

class Bottom {
public:
    Bottom( const Top& topLevelObj ) : _topLevelObj(topLevelObj) { }
    void printBottom() const {std::cout << "print bottom";};
    void printTop() const;
private:
    const Top& _topLevelObj;
};

class Top {
public:
    Top() : _bottom(*this) {}
    void printTop() const {std::cout << "print top";};
private:
    Bottom _bottom;
};

void Bottom::printTop() const { _topLevelObj.printTop(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your code will not execute due to an error in your code, figure it out.

Secondly, you cannot call function `printTop()` from your `Bottom` object because you have no access to `printTop()` from the `Bottom` class.

You could maybe rewrite the code in this way:

```
class Top {
public:
    void printTop(){ std::cout << "print top"; }
};
class Bottom {
public:
    void printBottom(){ std::cout << "print bottom"; }
    Top top;
};
int main()
{
    Bottom B;
    B.top.printTop();
    return 0;
}
```